# How can I pipe text from a text entry question into a highlight question in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I would like to let authors annotate/highlight their own texts in Qualtrics, but I don't seem to be able to pipe the response text from, say, QID1 to the next highlight question.
Is this possible in Qualtrics at all?

So, if in the first question a participant writes `I love football!`, I'd like `I love football!` to be the highlight text in the second question. The obvious solution with piping (e.g., `${q://QID1/ChoiceTextEntryValue}`) doesn't work.

Is there maybe a way around this with Javascript? Or am I simply doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pipe a statement into a highlight question. Think of a highlight question like a likert matrix where the words/phrases are the choices/statements and the answers are agree, disagree, etc.  The highlight text you want to pipe has to be parsed into its words/phrases.

It is possible to do this with JavaScript by including the maximum number of words in the original highlight text then have the JS parse the pipe into words and replace or hide the original highlight text words.